# JSON PySpark column name as row value

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following JSON data, which i read with `df = spark.read.json('file')`. I want to get the value "9ac2b5fc-d2c5-43a8-a9e6-244f02b93997" in the json and create a column as "CustomerId".

```
{
  "Statements": {
    "9ac2b5fc-d2c5-43a8-a9e6-244f02b93997": {
      "Accounts": [
        {
          "Id": 12345678,
          "Institution": "Bank Name",
          "Name": "Savings Name",
          "AccountNumber": "00000000",
          "Bsb": "000000",
          "CurrentBalance": "0",
          "Available": "0",
          "AccountHolder": "A",
          "AccountAddress": null,
          "AccountType": "SAVINGS",
          "OpeningBalance": "0.0",
          "ClosingBalance": "0.0"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Currently managed to get the Accounts part of it with the following

```
cols = ["id"]
df_statement = df.select("Statements.*").toDF(*cols)
df_statement = df_statement.withColumn("accounts", explode("id.Accounts"))
df_statement.select("accounts.Institution", "accounts.Bsb", "accounts.AccountNumber").show()
```

which return

```
+------------+--------+-------------+
| Institution|   Bsb  |AccountNumber|
+------------+--------+-------------+
|  Bank Name | 000000 |    00000000 |
```

I want it so it return something like this. Thanks!

```
+--------------------------------------+-----------+------------+-------------+
|               CustomerId             |Institution|   Bsb      |AccountNumber|
+--------------------------------------+-----------+------------+-------------+
| 9ac2b5fc-d2c5-43a8-a9e6-244f02b93997 | Bank Name | 000000     |    00000000 |
```

Comment: the customer_id actually becomes the name of the struct inside the `Statements` struct. you can check with `df.printSchema()`

Comment: The location of CustomerId in the JSON file is not "fit" to be interpreted as value. It becomes part of schema (field name). You will have to modify the JSON to move it from key to value side - something like "customer_id" : "9ac2b5fc-d2c5-43a8-a9e6-244f02b93997". "Statements" should be an array of JSON objects and "customer_id" will be part of each such JSON object long with "Accounts".

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this solution works for you but check it out. im using my own hosted json file with the data you provided

```
import json
import requests
from urllib.request import urlopen

header= {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) ' 
      'AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
      'Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11',
      'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
      'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
      'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
      'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
      'Connection': 'keep-alive'}


url = 'https://api.jsonbin.io/v3/qs/635c24e30e6a79321e378a29'
req = urllib.request.Request(url=url, headers=header) 

jsonData = urlopen(req).read().decode('utf-8')
rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([jsonData])
df = spark.read.json(rdd)

df2 = df.select("record.Statements.*")
uuid = df2.columns[0]
#print(uuid)
    
df = (
    df
    .withColumn("accounts", F.explode(f"record.Statements.{uuid}.Accounts"))
    .withColumn("CustomerId", F.lit(uuid))
    .withColumn("Institution", F.col("accounts.Institution"))
    .withColumn("Bsb", F.col("accounts.Bsb"))
    .withColumn("AccountNumber", F.col("accounts.AccountNumber"))
    .drop("id")
    .drop("metadata")
    .drop("record")
    .drop("accounts")
)
df.show(truncate=False)
```

output:

```
+------------------------------------+-----------+------+-------------+
|CustomerId                          |Institution|Bsb   |AccountNumber|
+------------------------------------+-----------+------+-------------+
|9ac2b5fc-d2c5-43a8-a9e6-244f02b93997|Bank Name  |000000|00000000     |
+------------------------------------+-----------+------+-------------+
```